# Microsoft.Data.Services.Client deserialization navigation attribute throws the navigation attribute must be represented as the link element

Tags: asp.net, odata, sap-successfactors

I use in the project "Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" call SAP SuccessFactors OData API, during deserialization API response throw exceptions as follows:

> In the {http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata} :
> properties Elements found in "WpghBS. Recruitment. TxtRecruitmentMicroService. Service. SFClientFactory. UpsertResult" type "inlineResults" attribute, And it is declared as a navigation property. ATOM in the navigation attribute must be represented as {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom} : the link element.

What should I do? Please help me.

I tried to grab it by "Fiddler". The result is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<feed xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <entry>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:key>beisenTest</d:key>
        <d:status>OK</d:status>
        <d:editStatus>UPDATED</d:editStatus>
        <d:message m:null="true"/>
        <d:index m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:index>
        <d:httpCode m:type="Edm.Int32">204</d:httpCode>
        <d:inlineResults m:type="Bag(SFOData.UpsertResult)"/>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```